# What are trust agents and why should I trust "Profiles trust provider"?

Tags: settings, security

I don't know if this is a new thing in Android 7, or if I've just never came across it before.  I suspsect this is a new thing.  I am using OctOS M, which is based on LegacyOS, the new name of CyanogenMOD.

In figuring out how to turn off Smart Lock, some new whiz bang thing that reduces your phone security in the name of conveinance, I came across another trust agent called "Profiles Trust Provider". Searching the web gives me a couple of Android dev pages, which are never helpful to explain anything (They restate the obvious ususally. It's pretty bad when you don't know anything and the man page only restates the obvious [to someone who doesn't know anything]).

Does anyone know what this is, why I should trust it, what the feature does and if it does what it claims?

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing, but found only this German discussion: https://www.android-hilfe.de/forum/android-sicherheit-antivirus-firewalls-datenschutz-verschluesselung.910/cm13-was-ist-trusted-agents-anbieter-fuer-vertrauenswuerdige-profile.802610.html It's pretty readable when translated.